# CMIS file size download limits?

Tags: java, cmis, ecm

I have a CMIS implementation with Java pointing to a variety of ECMs. I'm using an InputStream object to get my documents via CMIS. However, I have noticed that I am getting errors whenever my file size is greater than 50KB. The type of file does not matter, but as soon as it goes over 50KB the files will no longer download properly.

Are there download limits that I need to adjust with CMIS? Or perhaps I am hitting a limit of an InputStream object?

Comment: There is no such limit, but we can't help further unless you share code, ECM repositories (including versions) where you are seeing this problem, exact error message, and CMIS version.

Comment: can you please share your download method ?!?

Comment: it can be handled with `Java` but doesn't know if `Alfresco` handle it

Comment: do you have any additionnel informations ?!?

Comment: One possible reason could be a proxy server that limits your downloads at this size. Please check what is between your client and the CMIS server.